# Uploading multiple files using file upload control in apache tomcat

Tags: java, html, apache, jsp, servlets

I am new to apache tomcat. I am running apache tomcat in my windows machine.I am having a html containing file upload control.Using that i should allow others to upload documents.I am having another div in same html to list the uploaded files. While listing the files, i want to display the ip address from where its uploaded. Note the uploaded documents should store in my local drive. Guide me in doing this..

I want to know how to add servlet and jsp in apache tomcat and how to call it form html.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

you can get ip in servlet by

```
// This method is called by the servlet container to process a GET request.
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    // Get client's IP address
    String addr = req.getRemoteAddr(); // 123.123.123.123

    // Get client's hostname
    String host = req.getRemoteHost(); // hostname.com
}
```

and you can show in html page, you can save in database as wel

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)
- [`request.getRemoteAddr()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteHost%28%29)